# Can't load images to bootstrap carrousell from css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using the bootstrap carousel in my website and I want to add some effects to the images for the carrousel for this I need to load the images from CSS and not from HTML but if I delete the img tag then the carousel doesn't show anything and skips to the next slide.

this is a div tag showing how the carousel loads the slides.

```
<div class="item">
<img src="path/img.png" alt="Second slide">
<div class="container"> 
</div>
```

this is my CSS

```
.imagefromcss{
background-image:url("path/to/bg.png"), url("path/to/another.jpg");
background-repeat: repeat, no-repeat;
background-size:auto, cover;
}
```

and this is how I was trying to load the image from css using the class imagefromcss but no image shows up

```
<div class="item">
<img src="" alt="Second slide" class="imagefromcss">
<div class="container"> 
</div>
```

can anybody please advice how can I achieve this?

Comment: If you need background image.. why you are using <img> tag.. you can simple use div / span tags?

Comment: @kiran if I delete the <img> tag no image shows and it skips to the next slide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify width and height for the background image like below.

```
.imagefromcss{
 background-image:url("path/to/bg.png"), url("path/to/another.jpg");
 background-repeat: repeat, no-repeat;
 background-size:auto, cover;
 width:300px;
 height:300px; 
 }
```

[**Sample DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/75tJd/)

Comment: this works but the carousel is not taking the images.

Comment: check the url path of the image.

Comment: Then without seeing the original output, it is difficult to identify.

Comment: I just added the height as you said and it's working many thanks!

Comment: now the responsiveness it's not working.. please see live it here: http://www.djexotic.cz/

Comment: use media query to adjust the height of the image.